# How to show my custom woocommerce products in 4 columns?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I am building a custom woocommerce shop page. Right now they are showing in a single column, one after another.

But I want to show the products in 4 columns. Please help.

Here is my code

```
<section class="text-center jp-p-60">

      <div class="row shop-listing">

        <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 jp-p-15">
          <div class="bg-center">
              <?php /* image*/
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>
            <b class="btn btn-outline-white rounded-0 font-weight-bold"><?php /* price*/
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?></b>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>



    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `row` class on the `ul`,instead of `shop-listing` div.And add `col-6 col-lg-3` classes on the `section` instead of `.jp-p-15` class div.

```
 <ul class="products columns-4 row">

   <section class="col-6 col-lg-3 text-center jp-p-60">

  <div class="shop-listing">

    <div class="jp-p-15">
      <div class="bg-center">
          <?php /* image*/
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>
        <b class="btn btn-outline-white rounded-0 font-weight-bold"><?php /* price*/
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?></b>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</ul>


</section>
```

```css
.abc {}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" id="woocommerce-layout-css" href="https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/themes/jxta/css/main.css" media="all">
<section class="text-center jp-p-60">

  <div class="row shop-listing">

    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 jp-p-15">
      <div class="bg-center">
        <img src="https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-300x300.jpg 300w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-100x100.jpg 100w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-150x150.jpg 150w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-250x250.jpg 250w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-120x120.jpg 120w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6.jpg 500w"
          sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> <b class="btn btn-outline-white rounded-0 font-weight-bold">
 <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>29.00</span></span>
</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 jp-p-15">
      <div class="bg-center">
        <img src="https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-300x300.jpg 300w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-100x100.jpg 100w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-150x150.jpg 150w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-250x250.jpg 250w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-120x120.jpg 120w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6.jpg 500w"
          sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> <b class="btn btn-outline-white rounded-0 font-weight-bold">
 <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>29.00</span></span>
</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 jp-p-15">
      <div class="bg-center">
        <img src="https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-300x300.jpg 300w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-100x100.jpg 100w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-150x150.jpg 150w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-250x250.jpg 250w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-120x120.jpg 120w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6.jpg 500w"
          sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> <b class="btn btn-outline-white rounded-0 font-weight-bold">
 <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>29.00</span></span>
</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 jp-p-15">
      <div class="bg-center">
        <img src="https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-300x300.jpg 300w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-100x100.jpg 100w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-150x150.jpg 150w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-250x250.jpg 250w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6-120x120.jpg 120w, https://inprogress.duniya.biz/theme/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/p6.jpg 500w"
          sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> <b class="btn btn-outline-white rounded-0 font-weight-bold">
 <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>29.00</span></span>
</b>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>



</section>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I also want to show when the owner adds a product, it will be on this page automatically.

Comment: I dont understand how i can help with that. didnt my answer fix your original issue ?

Comment: Right now there are 13 products on that page. when I will add another product, there will be 14 products and so on. I want them to show in 4 columns. that is the issue.

By using my code i can add products on that page, but I want them in four columns.

Comment: It should automatically show in 4 columns if you do what i asked.

Comment: Your code is showing 4 columns, but in a static way. can you give me a solution how to post it in a row div. I am not so good at this type of column based css related problem.

Comment: the provided code is the main code sister. If i remove this code, my all 13 products will be gone from this page.

Comment: Ok m chanigning the answer a bit. wait 5 mins

Comment: Check my updated answer and ignore the snippet, just do what I mentioned in the answer before the snippet

Comment: <li <?php wc_product_class(); ?>>   

  <div class="shop-listing">

    <div class="jp-p-15">
      <div class="bg-center">
          <?php /* image*/
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>
        <b class="btn btn-outline-white rounded-0 font-weight-bold"><?php /* price*/
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?></b>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</li>